# How to make form display data from underlying bean in struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

I want data from java bean to be displayed on struts `<s:form>` on jsp page. So that user can see what is stored in database and be able to edit.

So, here is my action class with User bean.

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {

    @Valid
    private User user = new User();

        @Override
    public User getModel() {
        return user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

Here is my jsp page that should displayed User's properties when page is loaded:

```
<s:form action="createEditUser" method="post">
        <s:push value="user" />
        <s:textfield key="name" />
        <s:radio list="{'Male','Female'}" key="gender" />
        <s:select list="{'USA','Ukraine','Urugvay','Uganda'}" key="country" />
        <s:textarea cols="20" rows="10" key="aboutYou" />
        <s:checkbox key="mailingList" />
        <s:submit key="submit" />
    </s:form>
```

When user clicks on link to access this form the corresponding User object is loaded from db and assigned to `UserAction.user` variable.

But above form doesn't display properties of User like name,gender. User object is filled with data but form isn't.
I thought `<s:push value='user' />` will help me but it didn't.

Don't you see what's wrong?

**EDIT**. Here is code to fetch user from db:

```
public String getUserById() {
        HttpServletRequest servletrequest = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(
                ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
        try {
            user = userDao.read(Long.parseLong(servletrequest.getParameter("userId")));
            newUser = false;
            System.out.println("method getUserById()=" + user);
        } catch (HibernateException | NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

User is fetched successfully. It is printed.

`User user = new User();` exists for creating new user and saving it into db.

My interceptors in struts.xml :

```
<interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="strutscrudStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernate">
                    <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
                    <param name="exception.logLevel">DEBUG</param>
                    <param name="params.excludeParams">^struts\..*</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <default-interceptor-ref name="strutscrudStack"/>
```

This is an action that calls `getUserById()`:

```
<action name="gotoEditUser" class="com.strutscrud.action.UserAction" method="getUserById">
            <result name="success">/createUpdateUser.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/allUsers.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you load user object? Why do you use modeldriven? Remove `new User()`.

Comment: Why to remove `new User()`? I use `ModelDriven` to be able to directly reference User properties on `s:form`. I want s:form to display User props.

Comment: If you are fetching user from db then why do you need `new`? And show code where are you fetching user.

Answer (score 0):

To make  display data of loaded from db User object I have to use `ModelDriven` interface in my action class and `<s:push>` tag in my jsp page.

So, my UserAction class hasn't changed but jsp page got `<s:push>`:

```
<s:form action="createEditUser" method="post">
        <s:push value="user">
            <s:textfield key="name" />
            <s:radio list="{'Male','Female'}" key="gender" />
            <s:select list="{'USA','Ukraine','Urugvay','Uganda'}" key="country" />
            <s:textarea cols="20" rows="10" key="aboutYou" />
            <s:checkbox key="mailingList" />
            <s:submit key="submit" />
        </s:push>
    </s:form>
```

Comment: That's very strange. ModelDriven should push it for you :|